# - collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath: not called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've set header size the following way:

```
if let flowLayout = self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.myCollectionView.frame.size.width, 250)
}
```

The collection view indeed show space for header, but the header is not presented and the function that should create it is not called.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
{
    let reusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(FeedHeader), forIndexPath: indexPath)

    ...

    return reusableView
}
```

- The function located with the rest of UICollectionViewDataSource functions

[image]

Comment: Did you set the `dataSource` property?

Comment: @katleta3000 Yes. You can see that the cells are created properly (blurred cell), so the data source is connected properly

Comment: @Luda did you manage to fix this? I'm experiencing the same issue at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late, but it seems like you are missing actually adding the header, either in IB or registering it in the code using one of these two methods:

```
func registerClass(_ viewClass: AnyClass?, forSupplementaryViewOfKind elementKind: String, withReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
func registerNib(_ nib: UINib?, forSupplementaryViewOfKind kind: String, withReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom layout, implementing 
`func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(_: String, _indexPath:NSIndexPath)` might help